# при нажатии на кнопку в первом Activity создается второе Activity. а при нажатии на кнопку во втором Activity создается clone певрого Activity

Tags: android, activity

Хотелось бы разобраться с проблемой историй Activity.. есть код первого активити и он висит на кнопке под названием Settings. (код ниже)

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.settings_button:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings_activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();   // завершение Activity
                break;
        }
    }
```

При нажатии на кнопку у меня вызывается метод и я перехожу в Activity 2 (Settings_activity.class)
и там у меня есть так же кнопка сохранения Настроек (save_button) и вот на эту кнопку лежит обработчик OnClick (код ниже)

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings_activity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

в конце метода я закрываю Activity через finish();
и все бы ничего, но есть пару нюансов...

Суть проблемы: При нажатии на кнопку Settings в главном Activity я попадаю в окно с настройками
а при нажатии на кнопку Save я возвращаюсь в главное Activity.
Если я попытаюсь зайти снова в Settings и нажимаю соответствующую кнопку в Activity то у меня создается клон Settings активити. и так при нажатии на эти кнопки история открытия этих двух Activity будет сохраняться, а при нажатии кнопки назад на интерфейсе телефона я закрываю все эти Activity в обратном порядке.

Теперь вопрос: как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на кнопки у меня было два Activity без какой либо истории, т.е. что бы при нажатии кнопки НАЗАД я попадал в предыдущее Activity а не предыдущее Activity с истории.. надеюсь вопрос поставлен правильно и вы его поняли, буду примного благодарен с помощью.

Comment: Зачем вы завершаете `MainActivity` если хотите потом в него вернуться? Соответственно в `Settings_activity` нужно вызывать только `finish`, без  `startActivity`

Comment: Решил не использовать данный способ создания новых окон в связи с дополнительными проблемами его использования, более корректным было использование создание новых слоев, тем самым решил уйму проблем, Например таких как передачи данных между окнами. Там тоже можно это делать, но более извращенным способом, а с обычными слоями решил эту проблему обычным "binding" методом. Спасибо большое за ответ.